# Coloring point based on combination of two variables in R plot (without ggplot)

Tags: r

[Exmaplary image I want to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0iHk.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0iHk.png)

I'm trying to plot a result of survival analysis.
The code I scripted is like below.

```
six <- survfit(Surv(t, d)~ Rx + wbccat, data = leuk)

plot(six$time, -log(-log(six$surv)))
```

Here, how can i color each points according to the combined levels of `Rx` and `wbccat`? (there are 2 levels in Rx and 3 in wbccat, so 6 colors in total)

and I'm trying it without using `ggplot` package.
Thank you in advance.

Below are the data being analysized

```
leuk <- read.table(text = "
35 0 1 1.45 0
34 0 1 1.47 0
32 0 1 2.2 0
32 0 1 2.53 0
25 0 1 1.78 0
23 1 1 2.57 0
22 1 1 2.32 0
20 0 1 2.01 0
19 0 0 2.05 0
17 0 0 2.16 0
16 1 1 3.6 0
13 1 0 2.88 0
11 0 0 2.6 0
10 0 0 2.7 0
10 1 0 2.96 0
9 0 0 2.8 0
7 1 0 4.43 0
6 0 0 3.2 0
6 1 0 2.31 0
6 1 1 4.06 0
6 1 0 3.28 0
23 1 1 1.97 1
22 1 0 2.73 1
17 1 0 2.95 1
15 1 0 2.3 1
12 1 0 1.5 1
12 1 0 3.06 1
11 1 0 3.49 1
11 1 0 2.12 1
8 1 0 3.52 1
8 1 0 3.05 1
8 1 0 2.32 1
8 1 1 3.26 1
5 1 1 3.49 1
5 1 0 3.97 1
4 1 1 4.36 1
4 1 1 2.42 1
3 1 1 4.01 1
2 1 1 4.91 1
2 1 1 4.48 1
1 1 1 2.8 1
1 1 1 5 1", sep = " ")
```

Comment: Can you show some data and perhaps an image that illustrates what you want to have?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann I added the exemplary image and data as you asked. I appreciate your kindness!

Comment: now we just need to know which column is which